# Application based transactions are not coming in AWR reports

Tags: database, jdbc, oracle10g

I am generating AWR Reports using oracle 10g using @awrrpt.sql,but only system level transactions are coming.

My application based transactions like creating a user in database and fetching that user are not coming in those html reports.

Can anyone please tell how to enable that?

Comment: An AWR report shows you, among other things, the most resource-intensive SQL statements that were run during the period.  Are you certain that the statements you are looking for are among the most resource-intensive statements being executed during that window?  There is nothing that would suppress application SQL statements if they were actually among the most resource-intensive statements captured in the window.

Comment: Thanks justin,but if i want to see all the queries as a result of single transaction,what would be the best approach,without going trace logs time and again.

Comment: I assume that's why you opened this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907905/how-to-monitor-all-the-executed-sql-statements-as-a-result-of-single-transaction

Comment: Yes actually for migrating the server to new version i have to know the details of all the db queries executing as a result of my transaction,so if there is any way you know,it will be very helpful.