# How to monitor all the executed sql statements as a result of single transaction

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am in the process of upgrading our server from one version to other.So for this purpose i need the detail of all the queries executing in single transaction.
I am enabling trace logs for that but that is a tedious process as it contains system related queries also.AWR reports seems to be not working.
I am using oracle 10/11 g.Is there any other way in sql developer to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracing is the only way to see all statements executed.  AWR works by sampling active sessions; this significantly cuts down on the overhead and data yet provides plenty of information for performance tuning.  But this means that AWR will miss many queries that run very quickly.

To remove recursive queries you can run the trace file through `tkprof` with the option `sys=no`.